# How do I hear the metronome in my ears without the audience hearing it?

Tags: mixer

I'm looking to get this mixer - [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Z7567A)

And I'll have the whole band hooked up to in ear monitors so we can hear all of the instruments/vocals and metronome. But is it possible to have the metronome not come out of the speakers? Only go into our headsets?

I know bands do this. Is this mixer cable of this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual, page 12, you have a separate Monitor mix and Stereo Mix.  Via the 2TR IN switch, you can have a Monitor Mix containing the main Stereo Mix *plus* the 2TR IN input, while the Stereo Out only contains the Stereo Mix. (see the diagram under section 12 on page 12)

So yes, to me it sounds like you can, assuming you have your metronome on the 2TR IN input, you feed your headphone distribution from the Monitor pair, and you feed the PA from your Stereo Out pair.

Answer (score 0):

If the mixer does not support multiple mixes -> you can use another cheap 4 track mixer where you feed in a copy or bus of your mixer and mix it with the metronome.

Good Day

Comment: How does you do that?

Comment: If your mixer does not Feature a Monitor mixdown you can feed a copy (via splitter) the audio into a smaller cheaper mixer where you then mix it with a metronome. So you have the possibility to over compress the monitor mix so everyone in the band can hear everything properly without killing your ears. And at the 2nd mixer you ad the metronome!

Comment: Wow, I never thought of that. So if I have 2 Speaker outputs, one of those outputs would be a splitter? One split goes to the speaker and the other split goes to the cheap monitor? That wouldn't ruin the quality of the audio that comes out of the speaker right?

Thanks! And haha I just realized I said "How does you do that"

Comment: Yeah that would be possible! For live Bands it is typical to Even have 2 Mixers, One for Audience one for monitoring!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks man. Would you know if a powered mixer could power an unpowered mixer through the splitter?